# Force update of bound attached property

Tags: wpf

I have created a dependency property that is bound (in code) to the Grid.RowProperty attached property in order to receive change notifications when an object moves grid positions (this works fine).  I would also like to trigger a change notification manually in some instances, even though the RowProperty hasn't actually changed.  I have tried UpdateTarget and InvalidateProperty to no avail, they both appear to do nothing because the actual source value hasn't changed.

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks.